# Selenium Webdriver - Upload Audido File

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can we upload audio files using selenium web driver?

I tried google chrome and it did not work. It did not give me error but it was hanging.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on the upload link present in the webpage using selenium webdriver.
The window which pop-up next is the OS based which you need to automate using AutoIT.